# Push JSON Element to each of the Json objects in an array using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an api call returning an array of JSON objects with a format [{},{},..]. I need to add specific json element {Type: 'String'} to each of these objects. when I am trying the following code, I am receiving 'Unhandled exception SyntaxError Unexpected token .' error.

```
async.mapSeries(array, function(Item, Callback) { 
request("http://<uri>" + Item, function(error, response) {
         response.push({'Type': 'S'});

             console.log(response);
    callback(error,response);});
```

Based on the hints in the earlier posts, I tried the followin

(a)

```
 var resp = JSON.parse(response);
 resp.push({'Type': 'S'});
```

(b)

```
 var resp = JSON.stringify(response);
 resp.push({'Type': 'S'}];
```

but both of them didn't help returning the same error. Can any one pl through some thoughts on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: What requests library are you using?  Do a console.log(response)  what do you see?

Comment: what does `response` look like? It is most likely string but structure is important also

Comment: The response looks like this : { sub: '9SFXSF',
  IdSrc: 'SCM',
  ExtId: '6002',
  AccId: 'E7Q',
  TId:   'HY3T',
  pName: 'MINT' }

Comment: Using var express = require('express'); var router = express.Router();
var async = require("async");

Comment: @Jim: check error and response (console.log of both, before response.push). I think that you have an error.

Comment: even when parsed there is no array to push to ... it would be an object literal when parsed

Comment: Thanks for your quick inputs. When I comment response.push({'Type': 'S'}); like,  I am able to successfully receive the output !

Comment: @charlietfl i tried adding var resp=[];  before the async...line of the code. but not helpful.

Comment: That doesn't make sense either. Try @C. Windolf answer after you parse response

Comment: On what line does the error occur? A good starting point would be to indent and format your code so you and others can tell what the structure is. RIght off the bat, that would tell you that you are missing a closing `});`. It might be something following the code you showed that is causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `resp['Type'] = 'S';`?